# Generating Setup Project from visual studio community installer

Tags: visual-studio-setup-proje, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

I have generated visual studio installer from Microsoft visual studio community version. i want to ask is there any difference of installer generated from visual studio community version and visual studio enterprise version OR visual studio ultimate version ?

Answer (score 0):

The installer project extension is the same, assuming that's what you're referring to. There are no extra (or missing) features that depend on your version of Visual Studio.